# Asymptotic curve of hyperboloid

Tags: differential-geometry

Given is the surface $2x^2 -y^2 -z^2 =8$ and the point $p=(3,5,1)$. I must prove the lines of tangent plane at $p$ intersecting the surface are asymptotic curves. I find (using $\mathbf{x}(u,v) \rightarrow (u,v,\sqrt{2u^2-v^2+8})$ ):

\begin{align}
\mathbf{x_{u}} =
 \begin{pmatrix}
 1 \\ 
 0\\
 \frac{2u}{\sqrt{2u^2 -v^2 +8}}
 \end{pmatrix} , 
\mathbf{x_{v}} =
 \begin{pmatrix}
 0 \\ 
 1\\
 \frac{-v}{\sqrt{2u^2 -v^2 +8}}
 \end{pmatrix}
\end{align}

So $T_{p}S$ is spanned by:

\begin{align}
\mathbf{x_{u}} =
 \begin{pmatrix}
 1 \\ 
 0\\
 6
 \end{pmatrix} , 
\mathbf{x_{v}} =
 \begin{pmatrix}
 0 \\ 
 1\\
 -5
 \end{pmatrix}
\end{align}

Finding $T_{p} \cap  S$ amounts to solving:

\begin{align}
\alpha
 \begin{pmatrix}
 1 \\ 
 0\\
 6
 \end{pmatrix} 
+ \beta
 \begin{pmatrix}
 0 \\ 
 1\\
 -5
 \end{pmatrix}
 =  \begin{pmatrix}
 x \\ 
 y \\
 \sqrt{2x^2 -y^2 +8}
 \end{pmatrix} 
\end{align}

which results in:

\begin{equation}
 (6x-5y)^2 =2x^2-y^2 + 8
\end{equation}
Solving this (using numerical tools) gives the lines:

\begin{equation}
 y_{\pm} = \frac{15x}{13} \pm \frac{2\sqrt{x^2+13}}{13}
\end{equation}

However, solving $e(u')^2 + 2f(u'v') + g(v')^2 = 0$ with $u(t) =t, v(t) = y(t)$ does not seem to work and give a huge mess. I start to think I should have made some easy observation (does the fact that the surface is a hyperboloid help?) or have done a simple miscalculation.

Any help would be much appreciated.